# Automatic type conversion of array contents using Array.Copy()

Tags: c#, arrays, constructor, implicit-conversion

I am attempting to copy a number of arrays in c# using the Array.Copy() method. This method is supposed to automatically type-convert, however I am wondering if it will convert user-defined types if I were to define a constructor like so:

```
OldType(){
int param1;
String param2;
}

NewType(OldType old){
setParam1(old.param1);
setParam2(old.param2);
}

OldType oldArray[];
NewType newArray[];

//will this automatically convert???
Array.Copy(oldArray, newArray);
```

This is for use in converting from a legacy object to a new object. The content is exactly the same, the names are just different.

Comment: What part of [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx) did you not understand?

Comment: @M.Babcock - what part of that (long) documentation do you mean?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I don't think it could be much more thorough.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That documentation isn't terribly long.  There's only about half a page (if that) describing type conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easy way to make this conversion without leaving yourself or anybody reading your code in doubt: use LINQ.

```
OldType[] oldArray = /* Some logic */;
NewType[] newArray = oldArray.Select(old => new NewType(old)).ToArray();
```

As the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx) (pointed out by M.Babcock in the comments) says, `Array.Copy` is an O(n) operation.  Likewise, the LINQ code I wrote above is an O(n) operation, so there is no asymptotic performance hit (actual performance in wall clock time is dependent on a host of factors, so I can't compare the runtime of the two solutions without profiling) and you know that this code is correct.

Also from the MSDN docs:

> If *sourceArray* and *destinationArray* are both reference-type arrays or are both arrays of type Object, a shallow copy is performed. A shallow copy of an Array is a new Array containing references to the same elements as the original Array. The elements themselves or anything referenced by the elements are not copied. In contrast, a deep copy of an Array copies the elements and everything directly or indirectly referenced by the elements.

So no, Array.Copy won't "automatically convert" i.e. actually create new objects of type `NewType` during the copy, but will simply copy references to the objects of type `OldType` and put those references in `newArray`.

Comment: “so there is no performance hit”. Just because the time complexities are same, it doesn't mean they have to have exactly the same performance.

Comment: @svick As you made the comment, I modified the answer to include a more nuanced description of the performance difference.